# How to check for decimals at start of double variable?

Tags: c++

My goal is to check if the first part of a double variable is a decimal.

```
double value;

if (isdigit(cin.peek())) {
    cin >> value;
    if (/*value starts with '.'*/) {
        cout << "decimal" << endl;
    }
}
```

1 would not print "decimal".

1.0 would not print "decimal".

0.1 would not print "decimal".

.1 WOULD print "decimal".

How do I check for this?

Comment: Once you convert from string to double, it's too late to tell the difference between `0.1` and `.1`.   You'll need to do the test as a string.

Comment: However, your `isdigit()` test will fail if the input starts with `.` so in that case you didn't read the input at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `peek()` function like you have in your if statement before reading the input into `value`, but compare the result to '.' instead of checking if it's a digit. Too late to do it after you read the input into a double since whether the number started with a decimal point does not matter by then.

```
double value;

if(cin.peek() == '.')
{
    //it starts with a decimal point
}
cin >> value;
//do stuff with value
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Putting this statement before checking if it was a digit fixed everything. Thanks!